# Handlebars Accessing Non-Related Object in Nested Each Statement

Tags: handlebars.js

I have a scenario where I am using a registered helper `ifeq` conditional that is comparing the object being used within my each statement and a separate object that is public to the view file. i.e. `blog_comment` and `user` object.

However, I can't seem to figure out a way to access the `user` object for the fact that it doesn't have a relationship to the each statement of `blog_comment`. Is there a way to access non-related objects within a handlebars expression?

**Two objects that are publicly accessible by the view:**

`blog_comments` (Being looped through)

`user` (represents the information of the user currently logged in)

**Here is my `ifeq` conditional:**

```
hbs.registerHelper('ifeq', function(value1, value2, options){
    return((value1 === value2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this));
});
```

**Here is my view file: (comparing `blog_comments.userId` to `user.userId`)**

```
    {{#blog_comments}}

<i>{{createdAtDateSlug}}</i>
            {{#ifeq userId user.userId}}<a href="#" class="blog-comment-delete" data-blog-id="{{blogId}}" data-comment-id="{{blogCommentId}}">Delete</a></p>
            {{/ifeq}}
            <p class="blog-comment">{{comment}}</p>

    {{/blog_comments}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the solution. Since I am trying to access a separate object, I need to get back to the root of the scope and then access the object and its property. i.e. `@root.user.userId` in `{{ifeq userId @root.user.userId}}`. This change resolved my issue